# How to process 250K records in ResultSet in multithreading or any other faster way?

Tags: java, multithreading, resultset, cachedrowset

Currently my SQL resultSet brings around 250K records and which needs to be processed. It is taking 25 secs to complete the process. I am planning to do the Multithreading on it. But couldn't split the data from the ResultSet. When googling it says CachedRowSet, but no proper example for implementing that. Please some one help me on this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you need to wait for all 250K records before moving to the next part of your application? If not, then you can run the ResultSet code in another thread and use a producer/consumer pattern.

Comment: @karthikeyan Govindaraj Try to take data by set basis. Take data 1000 after 1000(pagination). Then it will be fast and gives better performance..

Comment: @KarthikeyanSubramaniam i can't do that. because I am taking from the join of tables. So if i take set by set, there might be chances of getting the same record again right?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis yes, I need to process that and display it on the screen.

Comment: this question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530531/reading-the-same-resultset-from-multiple-threads

Comment: @KarthikeyanGovindaraj Then you could still run the ResultSet code in another thread and have the main application thread update a progress bar for the user while they are waiting the 25 seconds.

Comment: Also, is there anyway you can refine the query so that it doesn't bring back 250K records. I doubt you are showing all 250K records to the UI.

Comment: can you use map reduce(with Hadoop)?

Comment: **Multithreading will not help.** There is still only one network, and it is not multithreaded. You should try to reduce the size of the result set before it is *sent,* with a more selective query, or do the processing at the server with an update.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query by joining more tables and also try to use this 
two key words

```
FETCH and OFFSET.
For 1st Ex : fetch = 1, offset = 1000
For 2nd Ex : fetch = 1001, offset = 1000
```

Please check this link 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx

By fetching set after set from database
You can use **pagination concept** 
It won't affects the UI at any case.

In case of Oracle : 
You can do it easily on 12c by specifying OFFSET.

In 12c,

```
SELECT val FROM table ORDER BY val OFFSET 4 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY;
```

To do the same on 11g and prior, you need to use ROWNUM twice, inner query andouter query respectively.

The same query in 11g,

```
SELECT val FROM (SELECT val, rownum AS rnum FROM (SELECT val FROM table ORDER BY val) WHERE rownum <= 8) WHERE rnum > 4;
```

Here OFFSET is 4.

Comment: How do you know the OP is using SQL Server?

Comment: Its the Oracle database.

Comment: For Oracle also similar Please this link http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_offset_fet_first_rows_only.htm

Comment: mine is oracle 11g so I cannot use that aswell. Also i need to join around 19 tables to get the resultset.

Comment: You can do it easily on 12c by specifyingOFFSET.

In 12c,

SELECT val FROM table ORDER BY val OFFSET 4 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY;

To do the same on 11g and prior, you need to use ROWNUM twice, inner query andouter query respectively.

The same query in 11g,

SELECT val FROM (SELECT val, rownum AS rnum FROM (SELECT val FROM table ORDER BY val) WHERE rownum <= 8) WHERE rnum > 4;

Here OFFSET is 4.

Comment: Yes, but will oracle keep track of the rownum for a join of 19 tables? It will be a problem right. If I execute the query for first 1K records, then if i am executing the same query, while hitting the DB for the second time it should be a single table right. If it is multiple join then will it keep track of that?

Comment: A `CachedRowSet` has support for such paging.